# Scanning a string into a list of tokens

Tags: parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, elixir, lexical-analysis

Here is my code:

```
defmodule LineScanner do
    @spec scan(String.t()) :: [Token.t()]
    def scan(line) when is_binary(line), do: scan_(line, {[], ""}) |> Enum.reverse()


### The function below needs some refactoring ######


    @spec scan_(String.t(), {[Token.t()], binary()}) :: [Token.t()]
    def scan_(line, {acc, fragments}) when is_binary(line) do
        case token(line, fragments) do
            {nil, "", f} -> [%TextNode{text: f} | acc]
            {nil, rest, f} -> scan_(rest, {acc, f})
            {t, "", ""} -> [t | acc]
            {t, "", f} -> [t | [%TextNode{text: f} | acc]]
            {t, rest, "" = f} -> scan_(rest, {[t | acc], f})
            {t, rest, f} -> scan_(rest, {[t | [%TextNode{text: f} | acc]], ""})
        end
    end


#####################################################


    @spec token(String.t(), binary()) :: {Token.t(), String.t()}
    def token(<<c::utf8, rest::binary>>, fragments) do
          case c do
              ?# -> {%Header{}, rest, fragments}
              ?> -> {%BlockQuoteCaret{}, rest, fragments}
              x when x in [?-, ?*] -> {%Bullet{}, rest, fragments}
              ?` -> {%BackTick{}, rest, fragments}
              _ = cp -> {nil, rest, fragments <> <<cp>>}
          end
    end
end
```

A brief synopsis. I'm building a scanner for Markdown syntax. It needs to pick up significant tokens but also intermediary text fragments.

Given that `token()` returns a 3-tuple, my case statement will need to test 2^3 combination. Since the `nil` case only ever returns a non-empty string, 2 of those are automatically eliminated, leaving the 6 below. But it is still rather clunky. This is what's going on:

1. A text fragment exists, but the end of the line has been reached.
   RETURN: the accumulator + text node
2. A text fragment exists
   RETURN: another call to scan
3. A token has been found at the end of the line.
   RETURN: the accumulator + token
4. A token has been found at the end of the line AND a text fragment exists.
   RETURN: The accumulator + text node + token
5. A token has been found and there is not fragment
   RETURN: another call to scan with the new token added to the accumulator
6. A token has been found AND there is a text fragment
   RETURN: another call to scan with the token and text node added to the accumulator

I'm racking my brain to figure out how to slim this down, but every case seems significant. Please help.